# WebFlux WebClient not sending certificate

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, spring-webflux, client-certificates

I'm creating a Java client, based on Spring WebFlux, that should send a request to an external endpoint, autenticating through a certificate.
I did a similar thing using the Spring's WebServiceTemplate, by specifying the certificate in the application.yaml file like the following:

```
client:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: /myapp/certificate/keystore.p12
    key-store-password: SUPERSECRET
```

Then by defining the SSLContext for HttpClient in order to generate the related bean to be used for the proper call.
Here's an extract of the context configuration:

```
private SSLContext sslContext()
  throws IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
  KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

  return SSLContextBuilder.create()
    .loadKeyMaterial(new File(keystore), keystorePassword.toCharArray(),
        keystorePassword.toCharArray()).build();
}
```

It turns out that I'm not able to perform the exact same thing by using the WebClient (from WebFlux).
What I did, following various SO responses and guides, is the following:

Creating the proper SSLContext by loading the same `keystore.p12` (I intentionally removed the try-catches from the following code to increase readability):

```
private WebClient getMtlsWebClient() {
  HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create();

  httpClient.secure(spec -> {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStorePath)), keyStorePass.toCharArray());

    // Set up key manager factory to use key-store
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePass.toCharArray());
    
    spec.sslContext(SslContextBuilder.forClient()
        .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
        .build());
  });

  return WebClient
      .builder()
      .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
      .build();
}
```

Then simply fire the call like the following:

```
return getMtlsWebClient()
    .post()
    .uri(externalServiceUrl)
    .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    .body(Mono.just(request), reqClazz)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(resClazz)
    .retryWhen(
        Retry
            .fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .filter(this::isAnyError)
    ).
    map(res -> {
      log.trace("Response payload: {}", res);
      return res;
    })
    .onErrorMap(res -> {
      log.error("Error response payload: {}", res);
      return res;
    });
```

Unfortunately what I get as a response is a 403 FORBIDDEN and indeed the handshake log shows the following message:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

While the previous WebServiceTemplate works as it should (I'm omitting the certificate chain):

```
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
matching alias: myalias
*** Certificate chain
```

Can anyone suggest what am I missing in context configuration?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Please let me know if you need some more information...

Comment: send a request to an external endpoint, autenticating through a certificate. For me It means client certificate. the httpclient has private key in its' keystore. the server side should import client certificate signed root CA into server' truststore.  Could you use some debug option to print out more detailed error information ?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's 2 years old, but this helped me:

```
private SslContext createSSLContext() {
  try {
      KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
      keyStore.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

      KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
      keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

      return SslContextBuilder.forClient()
              .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
              .build();

  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error creating SSL context.");
  }
}

private WebClient buildCustomWebClient(WebClient.Builder builder, String baseUrl){

  HttpClient client = HttpClient.create().secure(spec -> spec.sslContext(createSSLContext()));
  ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(client);

  return builder
          .baseUrl(baseUrl)
          .clientConnector(connector)
          .build();
}
```

source: https://gist.github.com/hsg/6152944726e46ababcf47398398b4140